# how to use if conditions in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get some results through query that would be in range from -50 to +50. now according to the range I need to have value in column comment.

The conditions are

```
    >=-50 and < -30 = very negative
    =< -30 and < -10 = negative
    =< -10 and < +10 = neutral
    =< +10 and < +30 = positive
    =< +30 and < +50 = very positive
```

the output i am trying to get is:

```
range  comment
-45     very negative
-20     negative
```

I can just get the value how can i set comment according to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like you want to use a `CASE WHEN` expression:

```
SELECT range,
    CASE WHEN range BETWEEN -50 AND -30 THEN 'very negative'
         WHEN range BETWEEN -30 AND -10 THEN 'negative'
         WHEN range BETWEEN -10 AND 10  THEN 'neutral'
         WHEN range BETWEEN 10  AND 30 THEN 'positive'
         WHEN range BETWEEN 30  AND 50 THEN 'very positive'
    END AS comment
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: hey Tim thanks for answer
my query is

 select user_id,TRUNCATE(avg(perception_score)*100/48,2) avg_wbs,
    CASE WHEN perception_score BETWEEN -50 AND -30 THEN 'very negative'
         WHEN perception_score BETWEEN -30 AND -10 THEN 'negative'
         WHEN perception_score BETWEEN -10 AND 10  THEN 'neutral'
         WHEN perception_score BETWEEN 10  AND 30 THEN 'positive'
         WHEN perception_score BETWEEN 30  AND 51 THEN 'very positive'
    END AS comments
    from notes 


group by user_id,comments;

Comment: it gives result.

282 50.00 positive
285 2.08 neutral
285 50.00 positive
287 9.63 neutral
287 40.62 positive
288 -28.81 negative

its never giving very positive and very negative could you tell whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your query is:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE range BETWEEN -50 AND 50;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) syntax.

```
CASE 
   WHEN range BETWEEN -50 AND -31 THEN 'very negative'
   WHEN range BETWEEN -30 AND -11 THEN 'negative'
   ...
   ELSE 'very positive'
END CASE
```